# Cannot activate virtual environment with a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, virtualenv

I read similar questions and have tried their suggestions but I still cannot activate my virtual environment. The hierarchy of directories is:

```
myproject
-- virtualenv
-- startvenv.sh
```

startvenv.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
source virtualenv/bin/activate
```

And, I am running startvenv.sh by:

```
./startvenv.sh
```

No error, but nothing happens. Why? Ideally, I want to open a new terminal and activate my virtual environment there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The virtualenv activates by **sourcing** (not normally running) the `virtualenv/bin/activate` script. If you want to do this in your own script, then you must **source** that script too and not just run it. Meaning:

```
source startvenv.sh
```

The difference between running and sourcing is that running executes the script in its own separate subshell, which is isolated from the parent shell (the one from which you called it) so that e.g. environment variables and other changes inside the script do not get propagated to the parent.

Sourcing explicitly does exactly that, executing the script in your *current* shell, which leaves all changes to environment variables etc intact after it finishes.

Here's a shorted extract from `man bash` (section about Shell Builtins):

```
    .  filename [arguments]
   source filename [arguments]
          Read and execute commands from filename  in  the  current  shell
          environment  and return the exit status of the last command exe‐
          cuted from filename.  [ ... ]
```

Comment: It worked. I added the command I used. Thanks!

Comment: A full implementation looks like this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/activating-virtualenv-and-running-python-script-in-bash-file