# Open a new terminal and source scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, virtualenv

I want to write a script to activate a virtual environment and run my server for Django project in a new terminal. My startProject.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
source virtualenv/bin/activate
python manage.py runserver
```

And, I can run this script on my current terminal by:

```
source startProject.sh
```

I want to do this in a new terminal opened by a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/myname/project -x 'source startProject.sh'
```

I tried this too.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/myname/project -x '#!/bin/bash\n source startProject.sh'
```

Both do not work. Why? I read other questions but I still did not get it. I am a beginner, so please assume no experience.

Comment: Maybe try `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/myname/project -x './startProject.sh'`

Comment: @wjandrea, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965475/cannot-activate-virtual-environment-with-a-shell-script) previous question of Heuyie it should be `...'source startProject.sh'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I open a extra console and run a program in it with one command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974756/how-can-i-open-a-extra-console-and-run-a-program-in-it-with-one-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to my experience the command should be:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/<user>/project' -x bash -c "source startProject.sh; exec bash"
```

Notes:

- The path of `--working-directory='/home/<user>/project'` is enclosed with single quote marks in case it contains some special characters as spaces, etc.
- The option `-x` means: *execute - the  remainder of the command line inside the terminal.*
- And our command is `bash -c "<commands>"`. That means we execute a new `bash` shell, which should run some `-c "<commands>"`.
- We have two separated (by semicolon `; == new line`) `<commands>`.
- The first command `source startProject.sh` will [source the script file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965475/cannot-activate-virtual-environment-with-a-shell-script).
- The second command `exec bash` has a meaning - remain open the current `gnome-terminal` window. There are [another possible approaches](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3359/with-a-launcher-for-a-terminal-application-how-can-i-keep-the-terminal-open-aft) to do that. In the current case the command `exec` will *replace the current process image with a new process image* - in other words it will 'kill' the current process and will execute a new (`bash`) under the current PID.

Further reading:

- Similar question, with probably a better answer: [how can I open a extra console and run a program in it with one command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/974756/566421)
- [How to launch `gnome-terminal` from StartupApplications](https://askubuntu.com/a/962068/566421)
- [How to launch `tmux` from StartupApplications](https://askubuntu.com/a/962820/566421)
- [How to launch `gnome-terminal` from StartupApps and execute an application as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965681/start-specific-terminal-on-startup)
- [How to launch `gnome-terminal` from Cron](https://askubuntu.com/a/955591/566421)
- [How to launch `gnome-terminal` with few tabs, each with different profile, at system startup](https://askubuntu.com/a/953036/566421)

Comment: It worked! Thank you for explaining one by one! :)

Comment: Happy to help, @Heuyie! :)

Comment: One more question.  Is gnome-terminal bash or dash command? Why do not I need to specify a shell to run this command?

Comment: @Heuyie: In the above solutions we specify a shell, because: **(1)** `source` is [Shell Builtin Command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) (find 'source' in the section [Bash Builtin Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins)), and in other case `gnome-terminal` will do something wrong; **(2)** We want to execute a second command to remain the window open.

Comment: `gnome-terminal` is a program, executable file that is [located](https://askubuntu.com/a/968698/566421) within a directory listed in your `$PATH` [envvar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Unix_2), so it is accesible as shell command. See also: [How do I modify my $PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3744/566421)

Comment: > it is accesible as shell command I did not know this! I was looking at list of bash/dash commands and could not find it. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @Heuyie, I remembered for this collection: [“Envoriment variable PATH” on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962945/envoriment-variable-path-on-ubuntu).