# Clearing terminal screen

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

```
Last login: Fri Nov 24 10:45:52 on ttys001
-bash: /Users/raquellorenzana/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/raquellorenzana/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
raquellorenzana ~ $ 
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
raquellorenzana ~ $ 
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
raquellorenzana ~ $
```

I have 3 failed commands appearing before/above my initial prompt on opening a new terminal screen. After typing new commands, just one of the old failed commands appears above my prompt every time. I manage to clear my terminal to just show my prompt by hitting edit > clear screen, however it's not a permanent fix. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question and add the content of your `~/.bashrc` using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: copy paste your .bashrc contents by typing `cat ~/.bashrc`

Comment: It might come down to just a typo. `/Users` is the user directory on Mac. `/home` is the user directory on Ubuntu.

Comment: @wjandrea, according to your comment I suppose this question is not about Ubuntu.

Comment: @pa4080 Yes, it's about Mac. I had thought OP followed the wrong tutorial or something, but I just noticed "ttys001", which is the Mac equivalent of "tty1".

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've messed up your `~/.bashrc` file. The way to solve this problem is to edit this file and find which commands inside generates these messages.

The directory `/etc/skel` contains copies of the files that will be copied into the user's home directory [when you create a new user](https://askubuntu.com/a/971846/566421). So you could compare your `.bashrc` file with the default one in this way:

```
diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

You could copy `/etc/skel/.bashrc` in your home directory, but, just in case, first [create a backup](https://askubuntu.com/q/962489/566421) of the existing file:

```
cp ~/.bashrc{,_old}
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Then you could compare the two files and command by command make the necessary changes in the new file.

```
diff ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc_old
```

---

I would suggest you to un-comment the following in the new `~/.bashrc`: `force_color_prompt=yes`

---

To apply the new file within the current session 
(without start a new terminal) you should [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/965496/566421) it by one of the following commands: `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`.

---

Additionally you could get coloured output of `diff` by the wrapper `colordiff`. First install it:

```
sudo apt install colordiff
```

Then use it in this way ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800578/colorize-diff-on-the-command-line)):

```
diff <old file> <new file> | colordiff
```

Or just use:

```
colordiff <old file> <new file>
```